# ExecuteReader error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, odbc

I have these lines of codes here, the problem is the `myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader` always get an error message.

Code:

```
Dim myConnection As OdbcConnection
Dim myCommand As OdbcCommand
Dim myReader As OdbcDataReader

myConnection = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Database=usermanagement;Server=localhost;UID=root;")
myConnection.Open()

If myConnection.State = 0 Then
    myConnection.Open()
End If
Dim dt As Date = DateTime.Today
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Dim strDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

myCommand = New OdbcCommand("select * from reserved where date =" + "CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY" + " and rm_id=" + Request.QueryString("rm_id"), myConnection)
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader


While (myReader.Read()) %>
    if (s == "<%Response.Write(myReader.Item("bsched_id"))%>") {

        staroom += "<%Response.Write(myReader.Item("room"))%>,";
    }
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "<%Response.Write(myReader.Item("date"))%>"
    <% End While
myReader.Close()
myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: You have any informations about the error you get, for example a message?

Comment: yes sir, I'll paste it here: "ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.17]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: Someone can destroy your database via url parameter at `and rm_id=" + Request.QueryString("rm_id")`. Use sql parameters to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Apart from that this is not valid sql: `CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to get the current date with an interval of 1 day, my goal here is to disable these dates and the room whenever a customer will book a room, I am still a newbie...

Comment: I have solved it sir using sql parameters, and only leaving the curdate(), thank you for your help sir.